# Упоминание, как в twitter

Tags: mysqli, twitter, php

Как можно реализовать упоминание пользователя, как в twitter или тут, но без автозавершения?

Пример:
Пользователь вводит [[@user](/users/36/user)](/users/36/user) и отправляет сообщения, потом скрипт обрабатывает и ищет в сообщении `@любой текст`, и если находит, то заменяет это на ссылку `<a href="/user.html">@user</a>`. Желателен пример реализации на **mysqli**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы попробовал следующим образом: в шаблоне, который выводит текст сообщения, использовать что-то вроде http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php и уже в колбеке сравнивать массив тегов на вхождение, и если присутсвует отдавать `<a></a>`, а если этого хеша нет в массиве (базе), тогда ничего не делать.

Comment: Я уже рассматривал данный способ, но не понимаю работу preg_replace, хоть убейте. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment:  Можно погуглить по такому запросу: `preg_replace hashtag php`, ну а если лень то пожалуйста: `/(^|\s)@(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/`